# Remote desktop to a computer that's asleep

Tags: remote-desktop

Is it possible to remote into my home desktop when it's asleep?  Is it possible to remotely wake it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you want wake-on-lan. Many VNC client software include it, but it's a minor thing easy to find elsewhere (oddly ios vnc clients seem to be more likely to have it, also where there are really nice wol apps).

[Here's an explanation for windows](http://uk.lifehacker.com/348197/access-your-computer-anytime-and-save-energy-with-wake+on+lan), it's even easier on mac (look in Energy Saver).

Answer (score 1):

Wake-on-LAN will be the key.

[Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com) covered it well here: http://blog.lifehacker.com/#!348197/access-your-computer-anytime-and-save-energy-with-wake+on+lan

[Read this thread](http://www.technologyquestions.com/technology/windows-xp/232840-remote-desktop-wake-lan.html) too if you need more details.

gl, mjb.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your bios and enable the 'wake on lan' option (if you have the option , other wise there is not much you can do ),
Also you might need a 'wake on lan' tool to wake it up .